# How to apply Google Programmable Search Element Paid API key?

Tags: google-custom-search

Based on the docs I am reading about the Google [Programmable Search Element Paid API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/paid_element), it appears that I should be able to apply an API key to an existing Google Programmable Search Engine that I have created and thus remove ads when the search engine is embedded on my website.

The docs that I linked state:

> Once you have a Programmable Search Element API key, you will add this key to your search engine using the Programmable Search Engine control panel. Navigate to "Setup" -> "Ads" and paste your key in the "Programmable Search Element API key" field. Congratulations, the Programmable Search Element API is now active for this CSE!

However, when I navigate to `Setup -> Ads`, I do not see any option for a `Programmable Search Element API key`. This is for an existing programmable search engine that is active with > 1,000 queries per day, which is linked to my Adsense account.

Does anyone else have this problem, or is there something else that I need to do in order to see the `Programmable Search Element API key` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Paid API requires you to disable monetization (unlink your AdSense account) first.

Comment: To further clarify - you must disable monetization, then refresh the page in order for the Paid Element API key text box to display. I had originally tried disabling monetization, but did not refresh the page.